# Deleting a line that contains a string

Tags: shell, terminal, sh

I'm trying to delete a line that contains a string pass through an argument, but I can't get it to work. I'm on OSX 10.9.

`sed -i '' '/$2/d' /etc/hosts`

Shouldn't that work? It just keeps the file as is. Nothing changes. My command is `sudo hosts remove junior.dev`.

Here is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

let $# || { echo No arguments supplied. Example: hosts add 192.168.2.2 mysite.dev; exit 1; }

if [ $1 = "add" ]; then
    if [ -z "$2" ] || [ -z "$3" ]; then
        echo "You must supply an IP address and a host name."
        exit 1;
    else
        echo "$2\t$3" >> /etc/hosts
        echo "Done."
    fi
fi

if [ $1 = "remove" ]; then
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
        echo "You must supply a host name."
        exit 1;
    else
        sed -i '' '/$2/d' /etc/hosts
        echo "Done."
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double-quotes `"`:

```
$ echo "$foo"
> bar
$ echo '$foo'
> $foo
```

When using double-quotes `"`, the variables are expanded, when using single-quotes `'`, they are not expanded.